# Print value if items of different dataframes are equal but respect condition with Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `df` and `table`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,2,6,3,6,8,9,2,1,0],
                   'B':[1,1,1,1,3,3,5,5,5,2]})

table = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[0,4],[5,10],[2,8],[9,10],[0,8],[9,10],[5,10],[0,4],[1,7],[8,10]],
                      'B':[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
                      'C':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9],[10,11,12],[13,14],[15],[16,17],[18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]})
```

my goal is to print the content of the generic row of `table['C']` whenever the following conditions are met:

- item of `df['B']` is equal to `table['B']`
- item of `df['A']` is belongs to the range of `table['A']`

I was able to achieve my goal by using the following lines of code:

```
for i,row1 in df.iterrows():
    for j, row2 in table.iterrows():
        if row1['B'] == row2['B'] and (row1['A'] in range(row2['A'][0],row2['A'][1])):
                print(row2['C'])
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get the same result in a more efficient and elegant way since `df` and `table` may be very large.

Comment: you may wanna use the `df.loc[]` function that allows multi selection with criteria, it should be faster that iteration.

Comment: I don't know how to use it to go through 2 df at the same time tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for create all combinations by column `B` and then `apply` for creating `boolean mask`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.merge(df, table, on='B')
df1 = df1[df1.apply(lambda x: x.A_x in range(x['A_y'][0],x['A_y'][1]), axis=1)]
print(df1)
    A_x  B      A_y                 C
0     0  1   [0, 4]         [1, 2, 3]
2     2  1   [0, 4]         [1, 2, 3]
5     6  1  [5, 10]         [4, 5, 6]
6     3  1   [0, 4]         [1, 2, 3]
8     6  3   [0, 8]      [10, 11, 12]
13    9  5  [8, 10]  [21, 22, 23, 24]
14    2  5   [1, 7]      [18, 19, 20]
16    1  5   [1, 7]      [18, 19, 20]
```